# C++ request for member, which is of non-class type

Tags: c++

I have a simple program. The main is provided by my professor. We're to write 3 functions called `enter`, `simplify`, `display`.

main

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
// #include "fraction.h"

struct Fraction {
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
};

void enter(struct Fraction* fraction);
void simplify(struct Fraction* fraction);
void display(struct Fraction fraction);

int main() 
{
    struct Fraction fraction;
    cout << "Fraction Simplifier" << endl;
    cout << "===================" << endl;
    enter(&fraction);
    //simplify(&fraction);
    //display(fraction);
}

void enter(struct Fraction* fraction) {
    cout << "Numerator:     " << endl;
    cin >> *fraction.numerator; // the line that doesn't work, line 31
}

void simplify(struct Fraction* fraction) {}
void display(struct Fraction fraction) {}
```

error:

```
w2.cpp:31:19: error: request for member ânumeratorâ in âfractionâ, which is of non-class type âFraction*â
```

the line in question

```
void enter(struct Fraction* fraction) {
    cout << "Numerator:     " << endl;
    cin >> *fraction.numerator; // the line that doesn't work, line 31
}
```

Comment: Also, when you write in C++ it is better to use references than pointers in `enter` and `simplify` and const-reference in the `display` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an order of operations problem.  You want:

```
cin >> (*fraction).numerator
```

Or more idiomatically:

```
cin >> fraction->numerator;
```

Comment: That was it. Can you expand on "order of operations problem"? I'm not sure what you mean. Is there a conflict between `>>` and `*`?

Comment: No, no conflict.  The `.` has higher precendence than the `*`, though.

Comment: @eveo: He means _precedence_ of operations

Comment: +1 @K-ballo.  Doesn't that mean the same thing? (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations)

Comment: @CarlNorum: Yeah, I wasn't correcting you. Precedence of operations is a more common term in programming

Comment: @CarlNorum: I think I'd use the word precedence instead of order. It's already pretty common to (incorrectly) assume that precedence determines order of evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

You have an [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) problem. This expression

```
*fraction.numerator;
```

is parsed as

```
*(fraction.numerator);
```

Try this

```
(*fraction).numerator;
```

or this

```
fraction->numerator;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having an issue of operator precedence(`* Operator` and `. Operator`), [reference link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++)

You could try:

```
cin >> fraction->numerator;
```

or

```
cin >> (*fraction).numerator;
```

Or the better way is to pass reference of Fraction to `enter`, `simpilfy` and `display`, for example:

```
void enter(Fraction& fraction)
{
  cout << "Numerator:     " << endl;
  cin >> fraction.numerator;
}
void simplify(Fraction& fraction);
void display(const Fraction& fraction);
```

Comment: `->` *does* dereference it.

Comment: Yes.  `x->y` is the same as `(*x).y`.

Comment: I know that but doesn't mean he has to do that

Comment: I don't get it, they're the same.  The deferencing happens either way.

Comment: I have to use the function prototypes as they are. @billz. Can't do &fraction.

Comment: @eveo I understand, pick any answers could fix your issue

Answer (score 1):

The unary `operator*` has very low precedence, so the order of operations of the expression will take place before it does. To resolve this we wrap the part in parenthesis to specify the order:

```
(*fraction).number
```

That way `fraction` gets dereferenced first and then we can access the object that is returned as a result.